# Can I retroactively enable Bitlocker on a dual-boot system with data on the partitions?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, encryption, bitlocker

I have a laptop with 1 hard drive, which has Windows 10 and Arch Linux on it. I intend to enable Bitlocker for the Windows partitions.

- It uses UEFI mode for booting.
- Secure Boot is disabled.

Is this even possible, i.e. can I retroactively enable Bitlocker for the Windows partitions (only) which have some data on them and **at the same time** not touch/cause harm to the other partitions?

If not, I could just skip the attempt and prepare for setting it up new entirely (which I'd rather avoid though).

Comment: BitLocker requires you to encrypt the entire disk.  Just encrypting the system partition isn't going to work.  Linux support for BitLocker isn't very good by the way.

Comment: I should be clear, BitLocker requires the entire disk be encrypted, if you are trying to encrypt the system partition.  If you have a non-system disk you can encrypt a single partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Hm. So is that a no? :-)

Comment: When I run bitlocker it says entire disk or used space.  Would the used space by Linux be messed up?  Would I be allowed into Linux after enabling BL?